# Singleton with dependency injection in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

Can anyone help me with using dependency injection on singleton?
here is my code:

```
class SpaceController extends ChangeNotifier {
  final SpacesPersistence _persistence;

  static final SpaceController _instance = SpaceController._internal(persistence: null);
  factory SpaceController({required SpacesPersistence persistence}) {
    return _instance;
  }

  SpaceController._internal({required SpacesPersistence persistence}) : _persistence = persistence;
}



abstract class SpacesPersistence {
  Future<List<Entry>> getPath();

  Future<List<Entry>> getEntries(Entry? parent, [String? keyword]);

  Future<List<Connection>> getConnections([List<Entry>? entries]);

  Future<void> add(Entry entry);

  Future<void> remove(Entry entry);

  Future<void> update(Entry entry);

  Future<void> setPath(List<Entry> path);
}
```

This problem is that I want to inject the persistence variable, but _internal requires the argument and _persistence is not ready yet.

Comment: Add code for `SpacesPersistence`, and Are you using any library for dependency injection ?

Comment: added it but I don't think it will help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Dart, is it possible to pass an argument in a singleton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56088670/in-dart-is-it-possible-to-pass-an-argument-in-a-singleton)

Comment: Are you using any library for dependency injection ?

Comment: not really it doesn't use dependency injection, I don't use any library

Answer (score 0):

Try with passing new instance in `_instance`. Here `SpacesPersistenceImpl` is a class which `implements` `SpaceController`

```
class SpaceController extends ChangeNotifier {
  final SpacesPersistence _persistence;

  static final SpaceController _instance = SpaceController._internal(persistence: SpacesPersistenceImpl());
  factory SpaceController() {
    return _instance;
  }

  SpaceController._internal({required SpacesPersistence persistence}) : _persistence = persistence;
}
```

Comment: I understand, this means i have to define in class, the Persistance implementation I want to use, am I wrong?

Comment: Yea, you have to define a class `SpacesPersistenceImpl`

Comment: What is the point of using factory here? Why not make static instance public and using this instance instead?

Comment: We can use, but this looks better while referring the class

Answer (score 0):

I simply grab a RiverPod provider, which gives me lazy initialization, discoverability as a singleton, and dependency injection via overrides for mocking during testing.  Details at http://riverpod.dev/

Comment: So no way to do it without an extra library? I feel like using riverpod is some kind of over engineering for a simple app

Comment: It actually scales downward to the small end fairly nicely.